# TFS2015 Build server: Access to user path denied when enabling the extension with a VSIX

Tags: tfs, vsix

I get the following error in TFS build server during building my solution:

There was a problem enabling the extension with a VSIX identifier of "". Access to the path 'C:\Users\tfsbuild\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Exp\Extensions\extensionSdks.en-US.cache' is denied.

I set the msbuild /m:1, but it does not help

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

**UPDATE:** In my case set the DeployExtension=false solves the problem. The error comes from the DeployVsixExtensionFiles Target in Microsoft.VsSDK.targets and in my case this deployment was not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Roslyn` directory (or another drop location for your analyzer, such as `14.0Exp`) and rebuild your analyzer.